# Buildpack: customisation needed to add opentelemetry

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, dockerfile, buildpack

I'm checking into buildpacks to create container images without Dockerfiles. Spring Boot’s build plugin uses a BuildPack builder image which will automatically detect that it's a spring boot application and builds the relevant image for us.

Now my question is, When i am running below maven command

> mvn -f $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/pom.xml -pl service spring-boot:build-image -B -e -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName="${{steps.acr_repo_server.outputs.acr_server}}/${{steps.acr_repo_server.outputs.acr_repository_name}}/${{inputs.microservice_name}}:${{ inputs.build_version }}" -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.repo.local=${{ github.workspace }}/.m2/repository

I can see it internally uses below 6 buildpack for the application.

> 

```
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 24 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.2.4
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 9.3.7
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.12.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.2.4
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/dist-zip          5.2.4
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.12.0
```

How can i add or ask maven to add this buildpack **paketo-buildpacks/opentelemetry** as well ? Is there any way to customise it or manually pass open telemetry build pack as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Opentelemetry to the end of the existing buildpack list. [See the example in the docs here](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/app-monitor/#apm-buildpacks-with-paketo-builders).

```
pack build samples/java -b urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java -b paketo-buildpacks/opentelemetry -e BP_OPENTELEMETRY_ENABLED=true
```

With Spring Boot see the [Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.buildpacks) and [Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.buildpacks) examples.

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <buildpacks>
                            <buildpack>urn:cnb:builder:paketo-buildpacks/java</buildpack>
                            <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/opentelemetry</buildpack>
                        </buildpacks>
                        <env>
                            <BP_OPENTELEMETRY_ENABLED>true</BP_OPENTELEMETRY_ENABLED>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```